# DateTime Formatting in repeater

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am trying to format the date time (`yyyy/MM/dd`) in a repeater which is binded to an ObjectDataSource as shown

(THIS WORKS)

`<%# ((MyType)Container.DataItem).CreateDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")%>`

(THIS DOES`NT WORKS)

`<%# String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}",((MyType)Container.DataItem).UpdateDateTime)%>`

I want to have both things working because sometimes the property UpdateDateTime is null, in such cases the second line of code handles smart.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: When you say the second line doesn't work, what does it do instead? What HTML is generated?

Answer (score 3):

I just tested you second line of code that you say doesn't work and it works fine when `UpdateDateTime` is null assuming that it's datatype is `datetime?`.

The your first line of code will in fact error out if `CreateDateTime` is null and that can be fixed by just doing it like your second line:

```
<%# String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}",((MyType)Container.DataItem).CreateDateTime) %>
```

Can you provide more information as to what the datatype is and what error you are receiving?

Another solution would be to use (again assuming `DateTime?` datatype but you could check for `DBNull` as well):

```
<%# (((MyType)Container.DataItem).UpdateDateTime == null) ?
    "No Date Text" :
    ((MyType)Container.DataItem).UpdateDateTime.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") %>
```